# Export table enclosing values with quotes to local csv in hive

Tags: csv, hadoop, hive, export-to-csv

I am trying to export a table to a local csv file in hive.

```
INSERT OVERWRITE LOCAL DIRECTORY '/home/sofia/temp.csv' 
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
ESCAPED BY '\\' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
select * from mytable;
```

The problem is that some of the values contain the newline "\n" character and the resulting file becomes really messy.

Is there any way of enclosing the values in quotes when exporting in Hive, so that the csv file can contain special characters (and especially the newline)?

Answer (score 2):

One possible solution could be to use **`Hive CSV SerDe (Serializer/Deserializer)`**. It provides a way to specify **`custom delimiters, quote, and escape characters`**.

**Limitation:**

It does not handle **`embedded newlines`**

**Availability:**

The **`CSV Serde`** is available in [Hive 0.14](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-7777) and greater.

**Background:**

The **`CSV SerDe`** is based from https://github.com/ogrodnek/csv-serde, and was added to the **`Hive`** distribution in [HIVE-7777.](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-7777)

**Usage:**

This **`SerDe`** works for most **`CSV data`**, but does not handle **`embedded newlines`**. To use the **`SerDe`**, specify the fully qualified class name **`org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde`**.

original documentation is available at https://github.com/ogrodnek/csv-serde.

```
CREATE TABLE my_table(a string, b string, ...)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
   "separatorChar" = "\t",
   "quoteChar"     = "'",
   "escapeChar"    = "\\"
)  
STORED AS TEXTFILE;
```

**Default separator, quote, and escape characters if unspecified**

```
DEFAULT_ESCAPE_CHARACTER \
DEFAULT_QUOTE_CHARACTER  "
DEFAULT_SEPARATOR        ,
```

Reference: [Hive csv-serde](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/CSV+Serde)