# how to export hive data to csv format with double quotes in beeline HDP

Tags: csv, hive, double-quotes

I'm trying to create a csv file from hive table from beeline in HDP . The csv file should contain double quotes for all the values. I'm using below syntax

beeline  -u 'jdbc:hive2://hostname' --outputformat=csv2 -f scriptfile.sql > outputfile.csv

This is created the csv file without double quotes. 
I tried with outputformat=csv it created only single quotes.

I know i can use 
 awk -F"'?,'?" -v OFS='","' '{$1=$1; gsub(/^.|$/,"\"")} 1' outputfile.csv 
to get doublequotes, but looking from beeline syntax itself to get doublequotes.

Please let me know.

Thanks,
Kumar.

Comment: Do you want each column double-quoted?  `"field1","field2",...`.

Answer (score 1):

Use concat('"',col,'"') to get your double-quotes.

For your HQL script:

```
select
concat('"',col1,'"'),
concat('"',col2,'"'),
...
```

Then you can run your command.
`beeline -u <connectionstring> --outputformat=csv2 -f scriptfile.sql > out.csv`

It's a little kludgy, but it works.

You could also look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33263331/2751573) to create a table with OpenCSVSerde, which allows custom delimiters, like double quotes.

Comment: I would also recommend escaping the columns. ```select concat('"',`col1`,'"'), concat('"',`col2`,'"'),...```